# CloudBoost CloudGeoPoint

Tags: database, cloudboost

I asked this question once before and because of a type got a smart alec answer that was of no use to me. So, I am going to ask again in hopes that someone can help me solve my problem.

The following is a code snippet that populates an array with locations. Everything works except for the GeoPoint

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var baseObject = new Object();
    var resultsObject = results[i];
    baseObject.id = resultsObject.id;
    baseObject.name = resultsObject.get("name");
    baseObject.city = resultsObject.get("city");
    baseObject.state = resultsObject.get("state");
    baseObject.location = resultsObject.get("location");
    bases.push(baseObject);
}
```

The line that has the issue is

```
baseObject.location = resultsObject.get("location");
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

Uncaught latitude and longitudes are not in range

Can anyone help me out with this. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

The CloudBoost SDK throws that error if your values are out of range. Latitudes(-90 to 90 degrees) and longitudes(-180 to 180 degrees). Try to double check your inputs.

Comment: @jdubicki, let me know if this solves your problem, you can flag it as the accepted answer incase it does.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem. No matter what values I place in the table. I always get the same error.

Uncaught latitude and longitudes are not in range

Comment: This error typically occurs at construction stage of CloudGeoPoint. Does <code>resultsObject.get("location");</code> construct a CloudGeoPoint object on the fly?